# arcpy.da.Walk not adhering to datatype filter "Locator"

Tags: python, arcpy, geocoding

I have a file gdb containing feature classes and address locators. I am listing and storing the names of the datasets using

```
arcpy.env.workspace = "C:\input.gdb"
(root, fds, ftrs) = arcpy.da.Walk().next()
```

The feature class names appear in `ftrs` as expected, but the locators do not. By filtering on `FeatureClass`

```
(root, fds, ftrs) = arcpy.da.Walk(datatype='FeatureClass').next()
```

the feature class names are populated once again, as expected. Filtering on `datatype=Locator` returns an empty list. I set the filter to `Table` as a check, and the list returned empty as expected.

I would like to know why the address locators in the file gdb are not being listed when `arcpy.da.Walk` is used to specifically filter out `Locator`?

Comment: What version of ArcGIS do you use?

Comment: If you use the datatype 'Any' does it include the locators?

Comment: @GISGe I'm on 10.3. I remember trying this in 10.2 as well, and it didn't work then either.

Comment: @ChrisR I assumed not adding any parameters would return everything by default. Either way, using the `Any` still only returned the feature classes, and not the locators.

Comment: Strange, it don't have any issue with 10.3 (when printing the name of the locators returned by da.walk). And what is the version of your gdb?

Comment: Your assumption is correct 'Any' is the same as leaving the parameter blank.

Comment: @GISGe I think that may have been the problem. I was given a gdb created in 10.1. Now that I created a gdb in 10.3 and created a locator in it, the filter is now working correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`arcpy.da.walk` was introduced in version 10.1 **SP1**, that must be why it didn't work with your 10.1 geodatabase.